# Session not persisting and cookie not retained between requests in separate frontend and backend setup

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js, passport-local

**Question:
**
I'm developing a web application where my frontend and backend are running separately on different subdomains, and I'm encountering a challenging issue with sessions and cookies.

**Setup:
**
Frontend: React application running on http://local.example.com:5173
Backend: Express.js with Passport.js for authentication, running on http://api.local.example.com:3003
I'm using express-session with a MySQL session store for session management.

**Issue:
**
When a user logs in, the backend doesn't seem to be saving the session in my MySQL session store.
Cookies are visible in the network tab after login, but they disappear after a page refresh.
When trying to log in again, a new session is created.

**Additional Details:
**

1. I've made sure CORS settings allow requests from the frontend domain and have set credentials: true to ensure cookies are sent with requests.
2. When I make requests to protected routes, req.user is populated as expected, so Passport.js seems to be working.
3. When logging in, I do get a Set-Cookie header in the response, but this cookie doesn't seem to stick around for subsequent requests.

How can I ensure that my sessions are saved correctly, and cookies are retained across requests in such a setup?

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const passport = require("passport");
const app = express();
const auth = require("./routes/auth");
const order = require("./routes/order");
const session = require("express-session");
const MySQLStore = require("express-mysql-session")(session);
const env = require("dotenv").config();
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://app.local.example.com:5174",
    credentials: true,
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
  })
);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Session ID from req:", req.sessionID);
  console.log("Session data:", req.user);
  next();
});

const options = {
  host: process.env.HOST,
  user: process.env.USER,
  password: process.env.PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.NAME,
};

const sessionStore = new MySQLStore(options);

sessionStore
  .onReady()
  .then(() => {
    // MySQL session store ready for use.
    console.log("MySQLStore ready");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Something went wrong.
    console.error(error);
  });

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      secure: false,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      domain: ".local.example.com",
    },
  })
);

require("./config/passportConfig");
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use("/api/account", auth);
app.use("/api/order", order);

app.listen(3003, () => {
  console.log("Listening on port 3003...");
});
```

passport config

```
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const { getUserByEmail } = require("../models/user");
const { verifyPassword } = require("../services/passwordUtils");
const { getUserById } = require("../models/user");

async function verifyUser(email, password, done) {
  try {
    const user = await getUserByEmail(email);

    if (user) {
      const isPasswordVerified = await verifyPassword(password, user.pass);
      if (isPasswordVerified) {
        return done(null, user);
      }
      return done(null, false, { message: "Password is incorrect" });
    }
    return done(null, false, { message: `User ${email} does not exist` });
  } catch (err) {
    return done(err);
  }
}

const strategy = new LocalStrategy(
  {
    usernameField: "email",
    passwordField: "pass",
  },
  verifyUser
);

passport.use(strategy);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (userId, done) => {
  try {
    const user = await getUserById(userId);
    return done(null, user);
  } catch (err) {
    done(err);
  }
});
```

Login.jsx

```
export default function LoginForm() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: "",
    pass: "",
  });

  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { value, name } = event.target;

    setFormData((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        [name]: value,
      };
    });
  }

  async function validateLogin() {
    try {
      const data = await fetch(
        "http://api.local.example.com:3003/api/account/login",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(formData),
          credentials: "include",
        }
      );
      console.log("hi");
      return data;
    } catch (err) {
      return err;
    }
  }
```

Made sure credentials: 'include' is set in my frontend requests.
Checked that the backend correctly processes and sends the session cookie.
Ensured session settings in Express are correctly set up, including saveUninitialized and resave settings.

**Update**
Removing the cors middlewear is now saving the cookie in the session store. But now, cookies aren't being sent with later frontend requests.

Comment: Have not tried running this but: Have you tried setting the domain to "local.example.com" since that is where your client is running?

Comment: in my component fetch request ?

Comment: No in your session configuration. app.use(session({... , cookie: { ... , domain: '.example.com' })) or 'local.example.com' or try skipping it